# c# filter search, multiple searchboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
List<LICENSE> licenseList = context.LICENSE.Where(l => ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseID) || l.LICENSE_ID.Contains(licenseID) ) && ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(hardwareID) || l.HARDWARE_ID.Contains(hardwareID) ) ).Take(10).ToList();
```

This is my current solution for handling more than one searchbox. Its a search function that combines 2 or more textfields in to a search. So my questions are: Is this an ok way to filter out the passed searchstrings. And how do i use it when the queries are decimals instead of strings? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is perfectly fine.

With regards to it being decimals:

1. If it is a nullable type, then you first have to check if it has a value, and if it has that it is not the default value for a decimal which is 0.
2. If it is not a nullable type, then all you have to do is check that it is/is not == to 0 which is the default type. I always just check to make sure it's greater than zero, based on the assumption that a license won't be negative.

I am going to assume that it's not a nullable type as it seems to be an inline declared var, so here is a formatted example for decimal:

```
List<LICENSE> licenseList = 
    context.LICENSE.Where(l => licenseID == 0 || l.LICENSE_ID.Contains(licenseID))
                   .Where(l => hardwareID == 0 || l.HARDWARE_ID.Contains(hardwareID))
                   .Take(10)
                   .ToList();
```

Interesting thing to note, if you don't know the default type of a field, you can always do

```
licenseID == default(decimal)
```

Comment: I suppose all of your answers are correct, but ill accept this. Thanks for your help guys, even though i obviously almost solved it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a foreach loop on the search boxes, modifying linq, for any of those.

```
        object[] a = {"seach", 5};                  // "Data"
        string[] Search = { "asdf", "asdf" };               //Search boxes
        var s = a.Where(l => ((string)l).Contains(Search[0]));      //first search
        for (int i = 1; i < Search.Length; i++)             //consecutive searches
            s = s.Where(l => ((string)l).Contains(Search[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks ok. You could also use a loop somehow like this:

```
var query = context.LICENSE;
foreach(var item in stringVariables) {
    query = query.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) || l.LICENSE_ID.Contains(item));
}
```

and stringVariables can be predefined or some algorithm to decide whether it's a search field or not.

Concerning the numbers (and assuming your column has type `int`, if it is a `string` you don't have to change anything), you probably have a nullable number, depending on your search form. So, you also have to check whether it's null or not and whether it's the right number. You may want to cast it to a string to also have the `Contains` function. But that all depends on your application.

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr: What do you mean I don't have to cast to string? My `int` type doesn't have a Contains function. How would you implement the `Contains` functionality with ints?

Comment: you need a reference to System.Linq; Compare uses System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<T> which means whatever the type of list it will compare given that you provide it with the same type as the list, not just strings.